# Given a <xs:union> element, how do I determine its type using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xsd, xslt-2.0

I have an XML Schema that contains the following type element:

```
<xs:simpleType name="value">
  <xs:union memberTypes="xs:boolean xs:int xs:double xs:string"/>
</xs:simpleType>
```

A sample XML fragment would be:

```
<value>42</value>
```

In an XSLT transform, how do I determine which type the value has, i.e., is it a boolean, an integer, a double, or a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In an XSLT transform, how do I determine which type the value has,
>   i.e., is it a boolean, an integer, a double, or a string?

If there isn't a schema associated with the XML document, the answer is that the type is always `xs:string` and the question isn't too meaningful.

**However, the correct question is**: With which of those types is this compatible (castable as) ?

**This transformation shows how this can be found out. It also illustrates the elegance and power of `<xsl:next-match>`:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="text()[. castable as xs:integer]">
     <xsl:sequence select="., ' is castable as xs:integer. '"/>
     <xsl:next-match/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()[. castable as xs:boolean]">
     <xsl:sequence select="., ' is castable as xs:boolean. '"/>
     <xsl:next-match/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()[. castable as xs:string]">
     <xsl:sequence select="., ' is castable as xs:string. '"/>
     <xsl:next-match/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<value>42</value>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
42 is castable as xs:string. 42 is castable as xs:integer.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a schema-aware transform, then this value element will be of type xs:int - the first of the member types of the union against which the instance is valid.

If you want to test which type it is, try something like this:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test=". instance of element(*, xs:int)">int</xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test=". instance of element(*, xs:boolean)">boolean</xsl:when>
  etc
<xsl:choose>
```